# how to implement data constraints to enforce minimum number child objects?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, constraints

Suppose each AssetGroup object must have at least 1 Asset object . How to enforce this constraint in :
a)  traditional SQL 
b)  NHibernate

I can check the number of children Asset before delete operation , but perhaps there are more declarative ways to do it .

In case of creating AssetGroup, does it force me to create an Asset first before creating an AssetGroup ?

Comment: If properly enforced, it should force you to create both an `AssetGroup` and its first `Asset` in a transcation.

Comment: See this question (and PerformanceDBA's answer, in the **`1:1..n`** part): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279984/defining-a-11-relationship-within-a-relational-database **and the much heated discussions...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to deal with that at the wrong level.

This is a business-level constraint, not a data-level one. Do the validation in your business layer and you'll be fine.

By "business layer" I mean either the entities themselves, or whatever you have on top of the data (NH/Repository) layer.

Comment: I see no reason why this issue should not be addressed at the database level.

Comment: @ypercube: if you like to deal with these things at the DB level, why are you using NHibernate at all?

Comment: @ypercube: sorry, mistaken you for the guy who asked the question. Anyway: we stopped keeping this kind of logic in the DB like, 10 years ago. Not because n-layer is cooler, but because it's more performant, scalable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Three possible ways:

1. Attach trigger to any of tables, which will do count(*) before commit.
2. Add field 'memberCount' to you AssetGroup and check constraint, which ensures (memberCount <=1), then on insert do: 
   a) manual 'update set memberCount = memberCount + 1'
   b) do this via trigger (looks like 1., but with stored state)
3. Use locks and check at application level. (as mentioned by Diego)